# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014/02/20"

Tags: java

I ma getting exeception while parsing the date.

following is the code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
    Date d = format.parse("2014/02/20");
    System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: your date pattern is different and also replace `DD` with `dd`.[Check](http://ideone.com/0jSVqp)

Comment: initialize your formatter like new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")

Answer (score 3):

Not only have you got the slashes/dashes wrong, you're also using `DD` (day of year) instead of `dd` (day of month). You want:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

As always, read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to find out exactly what pattern symbols mean - and if you find it's behaving oddly, check the pattern against the data *very carefully*.

I would *also* recommend:

- Using [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) (pre-Java-8) or `java.time` (Java 8) if you possibly can; the `java.util.Date/Calendar` API is horrible
- Specifying the locale explicitly
- Specifying the time zone explicitly

Currently you're using the default time zone and locale. While the locale may not matter in this case (unless it's used to pick the calendar system; I can't remember offhand) I think it's clearer to explicitly specify it. The time zone *definitely* matters; if you only ever want to treat this as a date (no time) it's probably worth specifying UTC - that way it's easy to interoperate with anything else, and you get day boundaries in obvious places in the underlying millisecond representation.

Comment: Just realized the second issue... :D

Answer (score 1):

Your dateformat doesn't match your string.

```
Date d = format.parse("2014-02-20");
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: `DD` is for day in a year (this is not me who downvoted)

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Thanks for correction, did not notice that.